# Integration of Uipath Insight with SQL DB

Tags: sql, dashboard, uipath, uipath-orchestrator, insight

I have a requirement to create UiPath insight business dashboard, using processed data in a custom SQL database, where it has one table for each process. If this integration is doable, I would be really appretiate a help from someone who experts.

Thanks